# Replacing row value based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm hoping I can get some help with the following.I'm new to SQL so I'm not too familiar with the programming. I'm trying to write a query in SQL that can do the following --
Duplicate/fill-out the ACCT # based on the most recent Timestamp.

Current Table--

| ACCT ID | Agent Name | Date | Approved Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | System | 11/20/2022 | 11/22/2022 |

So I'm looking to write a query for a way to replace the Agent name "System" with the most recent Agent name that had the Approved Date timestamp.

The way I was applying the logic was the following -

`Select ACCT_ID,Agent_Name,Date,Approved_Date`

```
from Internal_Table


IF ACCT_ID is the Same and Approved_Date is NOT "Null" Then Agent_Name = "System" is the most recent name.
```

That way the results the can look like the following --

| ACCT ID | Agent Name | Date | Approved Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/20/2022 | 11/22/2022 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a subquery within a `CASE` statement to get the `MAX` `Agent_Name` based on the the `MAX` date with the rest of your conditions.

```
SELECT a.ACCT_ID, 
  CASE WHEN a.Approved_Date IS NOT NULL AND a.Agent_Name = 'System' THEN
     (SELECT MAX(b.Agent_Name) 
         FROM Internal_Table b 
      WHERE a.ACCT_ID = b.ACCT_ID
      AND b.Agent_Name != 'System'
      HAVING MAX(b.Date) 
  ) 
  ELSE a.Agent_Name END AS Agent_Name, 
  a.Date, 
  a.Approved_Date
FROM Internal_Table a
```

**Result:**

| ACCT_ID | Agent_Name | Date | Approved_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Brandon | 09/09/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/11/2022 |  |
| 1357 | Jessica | 11/20/2022 | 11/22/2022 |

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/89Zsv7gc).**

*Per our Chat:*

If you want to get the results from the `Agent_Name` computed column into a new column, you can simply wrap the inner query in an outer `SELECT` statement to use logical operations on it:

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/reECwj-l)**